# I cant reach my website without typing www

Tags: web, web-hosting, http-redirect

my website link is  https://www.tweetanalyze.com/  i added tweetanalyze.com subdomain to be forwarded [www.tweetanalyze.com](http://www.tweetanalyze.com) on godaddy  but it isnt working without www like https://tweetanalyze.com  or http://tweetanalyze.com . My hosting provider says there is no problem in reaching it but i take this ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT all the time i try to go these links. What should i do to be able to reach my website without www? Thanks.

Comment: Could you see if you followed the steps similar to this article? https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/206028427-How-do-I-create-a-301-redirect-for-a-root-naked-domain-in-my-GoDaddy-account-

Comment: Yes i followed these steps  but it doesnt work

Comment: CNAME issue. Please make sure you add your CNAME on your DNS control panel settings.